# How to capture the URL of your serverless deployment in Bash?

Tags: serverless-framework

After doing `serverless deploy`, how can I set URL which my serverless application gets deployed to a variable. This is useful for me because then I can use this URL in the future to pass down to my Javascript website when it's built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who need this, I ended up doing the following:

```
URL="$(serverless info --verbose | grep ServiceEndpoint | sed s/ServiceEndpoint\:\ //g)"
```

Will set the variable URL, to your serverless app endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. I recently made a plugin called [`serverless-build-client`](https://github.com/tgfischer/serverless-build-client) that might help. In my projects, my client is its own Serverless Framework project, and in the environment variable section, I cross-reference the endpoint from another stack

```
provider:
  environment:
    REACT_APP_ENDPOINT: ${cf:my-backend.ServiceEndpoint}
```

This plugin will build your client with the environment variables in the `serverless.yml` file set. The meat of the plugin is this

```
const environment = this.serverless.service.provider.environment;
Object.keys(environment).forEach(variable => {
  process.env[variable] = environment[variable];
});

// later
spawn("yarn", ["build"]);
```

Before I made this plugin, I used another plugin called [`serverless-stack-output`](https://github.com/sbstjn/serverless-stack-output), which writes all of the `serverless.yml` outputs to a json file. One of the outputs is `ServiceEndpoint`, and I wrote a custom script to grab that value from the json file, and set the environment variable before building

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't just want the Service Endpoint, but also the complete URLS including paths to each API Gateway-integrated Lambda function that deployed to my stack. I've written up the full solution [here](https://therightstuff.medium.com/exporting-serverless-framework-sls-function-urls-and-paths-as-outputs-d2680da60464) with explanations, but in summary:

### Create a CloudFormation Output

```yaml
functions:
  my-shareable-func:
    name: my_shareable_func
    architecture: arm64
    handler: path/to/my_shareable_func/index.handler
    memorySize: 128
    runtime: nodejs14.x
    events:
      - http:
          path: /share-me
          method: get
          cors: true

resources:
  Outputs:
    ShareableFuncEndpoint:
      Description: URL for the my-shareable-func API endpoint
      Export:
        Name: ShareableFuncEndpoint
      Value:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - "https://"
            - Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
            - ".execute-api.${self:provider.region}.amazonaws.com"
            - "/${self:provider.stage}"
            - "/share-me" # this should arguably be a custom variable
```

### Retrieve the value with the aws-cli

```bash
my_shareable_func_endpoint=$(
    aws cloudformation describe-stacks \
        --stack-name "my-service-name" \
        --query 'Stacks[*].Outputs[?OutputKey==`ShareableFuncEndpoint`].OutputValue' \
        --no-paginate \
        --no-cli-pager \
        --output text
)

echo "Shareable function endpoint: $my_shareable_func_endpoint"
```